# ButtonClick to add contact - Cannot resolve method addViewById(int)

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

I am working on a program that implements a database so I can add contacts (phone number contacts). I seem to be getting stuck at an early stage with the error message "Cannot resolve method addViewById(int)"

I've written 5 other programs before this and have used the addViewById many times before with button clicks etc. Not sure what I am missing here (but I'm sure it will be obvious after someone points it out lol)

Here is my code:

**Java:**
    package cornez.com.databaseassignment;

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    /*public class EmergencyDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        /**
         * Construct a SQLiteOpenHelper object for the
         * emergency database.
         */
    Button addNumber;

    public MainActivity(Context context)
        {
            super(context, EmergencyDbContract.DB_NAME, null,
                    EmergencyDbContract.DB_VERSION);

        }


    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        String createSql =
                "create table " + EmergencyDbContract.TABLE_NAME
                        + "("
                        + "  _id integer primary key,"
                        + "  name      text not null,"
                        + "  phone_num text not null"
                        + ")";
        db.execSQL(createSql);
        addNumber = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.addNumberBtn);
        insertContacts(db);
    }
```

We can see the addNumber assignment above ^^

Here is the rest of the java code:

```
 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,
                          int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        // This is version 1 so no actions are required.
        // Possible actions include dropping/recreating
        // tables, saving/restoring data in tables, etc.
    }

    private void insertContacts(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        // perform inserts to initialize the database
        /*String tableName = "emergency_contacts";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("name", "OSS Surf Report");
        values.put("phone_num", "8436330268");
        db.insert(tableName, null, values); */

        String insertSql =
                "insert into emergency_contacts"
                        + " (name, phone_num) values"
                        + " (\"OSS Surf Report\", \"8436330268\")";
        db.execSQL(insertSql);

    }


}

public final class EmergencyDbContract
{
    public static final String DB_NAME    = "emergency.db";
    public static final int    DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "emergency_contacts";
    public static final String[]  COLUMNS
            = { "_id", "name", "phone_num" };

    public static final String AUTHORITY
            = "edu.citadel.android.emergency";

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://"        + AUTHORITY + "/" + TABLE_NAME);

    private EmergencyDbContract() {}   // prevent instantiation
}
```

The **XML** for the button is labeled as:

```
   android:id="@+id/addNumberBtn" />
```

Comment: `MainActivity extends SQLiteOpenHelper` - Is that really what you meant? Sure you don't want `MainActivity` to be an `Activity`, and have a separate class for your `SQLiteOpenHelper`? In any case, `SQLiteOpenHelper` doesn't have a `findViewById()` method, so that's why you're getting that error. `Activity` does, though.

Comment: Ok I separated them into different files(MainActivity.java , ContactsDbOpenHelper.java , ContactsDbContract.java ) and the error went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you don't need this button to insert the message,you can creat a class **MyHelper**extends**SQLiteOpenHelper**,the Button and the insert function shoud be in the**MainActivity**,[see here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

Answer (score 0):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` not an `Activity`, it doesn't have a `findViewById()` method. You maybe wrong.

```
addNumber = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.addNumberBtn);
```